# How to detect and manipulate files on a USB using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, usb

I have recently started a little project of mine using languages such as Python or AppleScript to manipulate files and other things on a Mac. I am making multiple different programs that do these things.

Recently I began to write a program that changes the desktop background to a file on the USB stick that the program is located on. It is intended to work across different computers, so I have to keep it on the USB stick.

The issue is that when I run the program from my computer, the AppleScript seems to not be able to find the files on the USB. I am also not sure whether or not I will need to change the code when I move the program onto the USB.

The program works fine when I use files on the computer itself, but it seems to come up with an error every time it tries to retrieve an image from the USB.

Here is the appropriated code.

```
set Username to system attribute "USER"
set Photo to (random number from 1 to 5) as text
tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"DesktopFolder"}
    move entire contents of folder "USB/Photos/" to folder "Users/" & Username & "/Desktop/DesktopFolder/"
    set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Users/" & Username & "/Desktop/DesktopFolder/Image" & Photo & ".png"
end tell
```

Of this, the line `move entire contents of folder "USB/Photos/" to folder "Users/" & Username & "/Desktop/DesktopFolder/"` is the one producing the following error `Finder got an error: Can’t get folder "USB/Photos/".`

What I would like to happen is that the images from the USB are copied into the new folder on the desktop, and then a random photo from this folder is chosen as the new desktop background.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously the usb drive is not at that location; in Terminal try doing `ls /Volumes`... do you see the usb drive listed there?

Comment: @I'L'I The USB appears in the list there (the name in the example code is different to the name of the USB as mentioned in the actual script)

Comment: So you'll need to put `/Volumes/<usb name>/Photos/` instead of `<usb name>/Photos/` and it should find it.

Comment: I tried that, and it came up with the same error. I also tried to change the name of the USB and try that (I did change it in the code), but that didn't work either.

Comment: Consider using Dropbox for files you want available on multiple computers... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that *Finder* doesn't understand posix paths (i.e. slash notation); it operates using **HFS paths**, which uses colons in place of slashes, and substitutes in the disk name at the beginning of the file path.

So, the equivalent HFS path that points to the same location as the posix path

```
/Users/{{user}}/Desktop/DesktopFolder/Image4.png
```

is written as

```
Macintosh HD:{{user}}:Desktop:DesktopFolder:Image4.png
```

Therefore, to point to a folder on your USB drive named `"USB"`, you would write:

```
USB:Photos:
```

Here's a modified and corrected/improved edit of your script:

```
set n to (random number from 1 to 5) as text

tell application "Finder"
    set F to make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"DesktopFolder"}
    move every item of folder "USB:Photos:" to F
    set desktop picture to the file ("Image" & n & ".png") in F
end tell
```

I've done away with a lot of your path references that were expressed explicitly as broken string fragments, and instead set a variable to store a reference to the location of the folder you make on your desktop.  That way, you can use the variable reference to target that folder for moving and selecting files.

Comment: Please remove the leading colon in the HFS path `:USB:Photos:`. Although it might work it's wrong syntax. Unlike a POSIX path which starts with a slash a HFS path starts **always** with a disk name even addressing the disks in `/Volumes`